# Conditional Statements: selecting/assigning a variable per row

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a data set with 2 VPs and 350 interval values for each. I am writing an if loop to select when a minimum value of VP1 overlaps with the maximum value of VP2.

The data usually sorts by VP, but I arranged to sort by minimum since it is a timeframe.

I ran the following code that worked to assign 0 or 1 when the values overlap the previous item, but it does not account for what the previous item is (ie. whether the previous item is VP1 or VP2).

```
  for (i in 2:length(df$newvariable)) {
      if (df$minimum[i] < df$maximum[i-1]){
        df$newvariable[i] <- 0
      } else {
        df$newvariable[i] <- 1
      }
   }
```

I want to say `if df$minimum[i] of VP1 < df$maximum[i] of VP2, then df$newvariable = 0. Otherwise, df$newvariable = 1.`

I have not been able to find how to make it conditional per each row and loop again. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Many thanks.

Sample Data:

```
    VP  xmin  xmax 
    1       0     6
    2       0     2
    2       6     14
    1       14    24
    2       20    30
    1       30    36
```

... And so on for 600 or so rows.

Desired Output:

```
   VP    xmin  xmax  newvariable
    1       0     6           -
    2       0     2           0
    2       6     14          1
    1       14    24          1
    2       20    30          0
    1       30    36          1
```

If I have a dataframe that had another variable and I subsetted to only look at one part of the variable. For example, variable = talking and the assignments are 1 (yes) or 0 (no). I originally subsetted to just look at 0 and create new variables, like quiet_together. However, I want to put these dataframes back together but have added columns in the separate dataframes. If I want the same exact thing as described above but with the dataframe together (instead of 2 separate ones), how would I specify for the each assigned variable? I want to end up with two new columns based on xmin and xmax values while accounting for the value in the talking variable. The new columns would be talk_together (for the 1 value of the talking variable) and quiet_together (for the 0 value of the talking variable, when xmin <= xmax for the previous line.

For example:

Sample Data:

```
    VP  xmin  xmax    talking 

    1       0     6       0

    2       0     2       0

    2       2     6       1

    2       6     14      0

    1       6     14      1 

    2       14    24      1     

    1       14    20      0

    1       20    30      1

    2       24    32      0

    1       30    32      0
```

... And so on for 600 or so rows.

Desired Output:

```
    VP  xmin  xmax    talking  talk_together  quiet_together

    1       0     6       0            0            0

    2       0     2       0            0            0  

    2       2     6       1            0            0

    2       6     14      0            0            0

    1       6     14      1            0            0 

    1       14    20      0            0            0     

    2       14    24      1            1            0

    1       20    30      1            1            0

    2       24    32      0            0            1

    1       30    32      0            0            1
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output to help you better.

Comment: Data and expected output would really help. This rbloggers entry how to access other cells in a frame while using apply() may help you as well. https://www.r-bloggers.com/access-individual-elements-of-a-row-while-using-the-apply-function-on-your-dataframe-or-applying-down-while-thinking-across/

Comment: Regarding your sample data: can you present it in a way that can be copy/pasted into an R console? You can put your dataframe (or the head of it, or whatever) into `dput()` to get this.

Comment: I tried adding sample data to the edited post. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lag` from `dplyr` to compare with previous `xmax` value.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(newvariable = as.integer(xmin >= lag(xmax)))

#  VP xmin xmax newvariable
#1  1    0    6          NA
#2  2    0    2           0
#3  2    6   14           1
#4  1   14   24           1
#5  2   20   30           0
#6  1   30   36           1
```

Or `shift` with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, newvariable := +(xmin >= shift(xmax))]
```

---

Base R alternatives are :

```
df$newvariable <- as.integer(c(NA, df$xmin[-1] >= df$xmax[-nrow(df)]))
```

and

```
df$newvariable <- +c(NA, tail(df$xmin, -1) >= head(df$xmax, -1))
```

Answer (score -1):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, newvariable := as.integer(xmin >= shift(xmax))]
```